# Android DialogFragment - implement SearchView widget from toolbar inflated menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, searchview

As the title of the question says, I am trying to implement the `SearchView` widget placed in a toolbar of a `DialogFragment`. The menu is inflated using the `inflateMenu` method of the toolbar.

**Note** : The dialog fragment itself is called inside another Fragment, not an Activity

Here is how I call the dialogFragment:

```
SearchFragment searchDialog = new SearchFragment();
searchDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullscreenDialogFragment);
searchDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "search");
```

Here is my `menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.hubsante.Fragment.SearchFragment">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Rechercher"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

And the implementation of the menu

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_objective_details);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);    

@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search){
            SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
            search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                    return true;

                }

            });
        }
        return true;
    }
```

No toast is displayed when a query is submitted! Even when I try to update a TextView inside the dialogfragment it is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        final SearchView searchView= (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();               searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_view_helper));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    searchView.clearFocus();
                // Your toast message
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String input) {
                return  false;
            }

        });
        return true;
    }
```

Instead of trying to use a method onMenuItemClick, you can introduce the searchview in onCreateOptionsMenu() and set the listener in there. This is done in host activity class but you can override it in a fragment

Comment: `getActivity().getApplicationContext` is not working. Actually the `onQueryTextSubmitted` method is never called

Comment: I am updating my answer  based on the code I wrote that works. You should change the values according to your project